# How to install Material UI on Preact?

Tags: material-ui, preact

I've read that the last version of Material UI is incompatible with Preact, but previous one works with it, some people integrated some of previous versions. But I don't know which particular versions and I how can I install one of them. Can anybody help?

Comment: Hey Liza, basing on your comment on below answer, could you provide some info over the usage of Material UI with Preact? The installation is easy but I've ran into an problem with element anchors (i.e. dropdown menus are showing in wrong places).

Comment: Hey @itwasntme, yes some of components are not working properly and dropdown is among them. We had to make our own dropdown using List component. Also dialog didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Material Design Components](https://material.io/develop/web/) with Preact by using the [preact-material-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact-material-components) package.

You can install it either by using npm:

```
npm i preact-material-components
```

Or by using yarn:

```
yarn add preact-material-components
```

To use a component in your project, in this example a Button, import the component and its CSS:

```
import { h } from 'preact'

import { Button } from 'preact-material-components/Button'
import 'preact-material-components/Button/style.css'

export const ChattyButton = () => (
  <Button raised onClick={e => alert('You clicked the button!')}>Click me</Button>
)
```

Now preact-material-components v1.5.5 is still depending on MDC v0.39, while the latest version of MDC is v0.42, but I'm sure it will be updated soon enough as I couldn't find any info about any breaking changes between the versions.

Comment: Thank you, I know this library, but it's not the same as Material UI. My colleague have alreary installed Material UI 1.2.0 on Preact somehow.